# How to reset a picture boxes position back to the left side of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a basic racing game in C# for an assignment where two picture boxes race from the left side of the form to the right side. What I am struggling with is resetting the position back to the 1st pixel on the left side of the form once the picture box has reached the end of the form on the right side. At the moment the picture boxes just keep going right and then disappear from the form and never come back.

That is what the layout of the game looks like:

[image]

I've tried searching google for snippets of code or even examples on how I might achieve this and have yet to find anything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public partial class frmRacing : Form
{
    public frmRacing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //This is the segment of intergers and the randomizer.
    Random r = new Random();
    int dir = 1;
    int min, sec, ms = 0;

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    //This is the timer for "Player One". It moves the players picture box across the form at a random speed between 1-10 and times how long it takes to complete the total laps.
    private void tmrOne_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dir = r.Next(1, 10);
        picStark.Left += dir;
        lblTimer1.Text = min + ":" + sec + ":" + ms.ToString();
        ms++;

        if (ms > 100)
        {
            sec++;
            ms = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            ms++;
        }

        if (sec > 60)
        {
            min++;
            sec = 0;
        }
    }

    //This is the timer for "Player Two". It moves the players picture box across the form at a random speed between 1-10 and times how long it takes to complete the total laps.
    private void tmrTwo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dir = r.Next(1, 10);
        picLannister.Left += dir;
        lblTimer2.Text = min + ":" + sec + ":" + ms.ToString();
        ms++;

        if (ms > 100)
        {
            sec++;
            ms = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            ms++;
        }

        if (sec > 60)
        {
            min++;
            sec = 0;
        }
    }

    //This is the start button. It enables all the timers and starts the race.
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrOne.Enabled = true;
        tmrTwo.Enabled = true;
        tmrThree.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void hsbLaps_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        lblLaps3.Text = lblLaps3.Text + 1;
    }

    //This is the overall timer for the race.
    private void tmrThree_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTimer3.Text = min + ":" + sec + ":" + ms.ToString();
        ms++;

        if (ms > 100)
        {
            sec++;
            ms = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            ms++;
        }

        if (sec > 60)
        {
            min++;
            sec = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you've tried? Something simple would be 

`if (picture.x >= form.x) 

{ picture.x = 0 // or whatever the starting pixel is }`

Comment: @TobyBloem, that should be `picture.Left` and `form.ClientSize.Width`.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I had no idea what to try. All I have is the picture boxes moving from left to right and eventually disappearing from the form. As for your comment above, I've just given that a try but I'm a little confused. When I put in form.ClientSize.Width it tells me that "form" does not exist in this current context. I tried renaming it to that of which I renamed the form but that doesn't work either. I'm really new to programming and I enjoy it but it can definitely be rather frustrating! :)

Comment: @jmcilhinney Cheers for the correct property names, just wanted to throw some quick pseudocode out there.

Comment: @GeorgeGarvin Can you edit your original post with the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method which you call at the end of your tick events which checks if the `Left` property is greater than the width of your form.

```
private void ResetPicture(PictureBox pb)
{
    // check if picture box left property is greater than the width
    // of your form - the width of your picturebox
    if (pb.Left >= this.Width - pb.Width)
    {
        // the picture has won the game, reset it
        pb.Left = 1;
    }
}
```